# I want the full list of ethereum smart‑contracts whose balances increased by 1000 Ethers above the past week

Tags: ether, balances, explorers

How to make this kind of query using my 200kb/s second Internet connection speed ?

With such speed, there’s no possibility to run an archival node (except maybe with a service allowing to download only recent blocks without the previous ones).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [Ethereum Public Dataset](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/ethereum/crypto-ethereum-blockchain?filter=solution-type:dataset&filter=category:economics&id=999d739c-de61-4550-8d9c-0753ca827cd3) and [Google BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/), I was able to find my answer :

```
#standardSQL
-- MIT License
declare stamp TIMESTAMP default (SELECT MAX(block_timestamp) from `bigquery-public-data.crypto_ethereum.traces`);

with old_double_entry_book as (
    -- debits
    select to_address as address, value as value
    from `bigquery-public-data.crypto_ethereum.traces`
    where to_address is not null
    and status = 1
    and `bigquery-public-data.crypto_ethereum.traces`.block_timestamp<TIMESTAMP_SUB(stamp, INTERVAL 168 HOUR)
    and (call_type not in ('delegatecall', 'callcode', 'staticcall') or call_type is null)
    union all
    -- credits
    select from_address as address, -value as value
    from `bigquery-public-data.crypto_ethereum.traces`
    where from_address is not null
    and status = 1
    and `bigquery-public-data.crypto_ethereum.traces`.block_timestamp<TIMESTAMP_SUB(stamp, INTERVAL 168 HOUR)
    and (call_type not in ('delegatecall', 'callcode', 'staticcall') or call_type is null)
), double_entry_book as (
    -- debits
    select to_address as address, value as value
    from `bigquery-public-data.crypto_ethereum.traces`
    where to_address is not null
    and status = 1
    and (call_type not in ('delegatecall', 'callcode', 'staticcall') or call_type is null)
    union all
    -- credits
    select from_address as address, -value as value
    from `bigquery-public-data.crypto_ethereum.traces`
    where from_address is not null
    and status = 1
    and (call_type not in ('delegatecall', 'callcode', 'staticcall') or call_type is null)
)
select concat('https://etherscan.io/address/',address) as adress, sum(value) as balance
from double_entry_book
left join (SELECT address as shah, sum(value) as eulav from old_double_entry_book     where exists (SELECT `bigquery-public-data.crypto_ethereum.contracts`.address from `bigquery-public-data.crypto_ethereum.contracts` where `bigquery-public-data.crypto_ethereum.contracts`.address = old_double_entry_book.address) group by shah order by eulav desc) wee on wee.shah= double_entry_book.address
where exists (SELECT `bigquery-public-data.crypto_ethereum.contracts`.address from `bigquery-public-data.crypto_ethereum.contracts` where `bigquery-public-data.crypto_ethereum.contracts`.address = double_entry_book.address) and wee.eulav<500000000000000000000.0
group by adress
order by balance desc
limit 100
```

Of course there’s might be better but I don’t know how to use tables defined using `with` using previous table defined in the same `with` statement so I’m using twice the same subquery for `old_double_entry_book`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [Ethereum Public Dataset](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/ethereum/crypto-ethereum-blockchain?filter=solution-type:dataset&filter=category:economics&id=999d739c-de61-4550-8d9c-0753ca827cd3) and [Google BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/).
This is Ethereum blockchain data picked be Google on daily basis and saved into cloud data warehouse.  The data is available for everybody to query.

Here is an article that one could use as a tutorial for writing BigQuery requests to Ethereum dataset: [How to Query Balances for all Ethereum Addresses in BigQuery](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-query-balances-for-all-ethereum-addresses-in-bigquery-fb594e4034a7).

Comment: Thanks but I suppose each query will cost a lot of money, right ?

Comment: Not sure how many queries do you need, but Google offers 1 TB of queries per month for free, and this should be enough fore several queries.

Comment: You should had checked the links ! Because it seems the dataset is no longer available : https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/dataset/bigquery-public-data:ethereum_blockchain

Comment: The dataset is indeed available: https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/ethereum/crypto-ethereum-blockchain?filter=solution-type:dataset&filter=category:economics&id=999d739c-de61-4550-8d9c-0753ca827cd3 , however some links in the article may be outdated.